# Do I have to instantiate objects to read the docs on them?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.6

Let's say I'm running Python3, and I want to know the docs of about `re.compile()`

I can

```
import re
help(re.compile)
```

This tells me very little,

> Help on function compile in module re:
>
> `compile(pattern, flags=0)` Compile a regular expression pattern, returning a pattern object.

Now, I want to find out more about the "pattern object" so I do `help(re)` and look for `/pattern object/` I see two occurrences, but neither of them tell me more about this object. Or, even how to find more information about this object, so I try a shot in the dark,

```
help(re.compile(''))
```

This only works because `re.compile` takes an extra string -- it's even more difficult if it doesn't. What is the easiest way to find the documents on the object returned by `re.compile('')`, does it require instantiation?

Comment: There's really no way to figure out the return value/type of a function in python without actually calling it.

Comment: The most helpful way for me is to read the online docs (the site is [docs.python.org](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html)) of whichever module I'm currently working with. Obviously, going online is not always an option for every developer.